# Highcharts multiple columns with average

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new to html/javascript development and would like to use a highcharts chart simular to this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic but with the annual average for each city displayed in a line chart (ie the same chart repeated 12 times). I have used SQL to generate the average so don't need the code for that but I can't seem to get the formatting right when creating the chart.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

`code`

```
Highcharts.chart('content-daily-delivery-status', {

    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        width: width
    },
    title: {  text: 'Weekly Delivery Report'    },

    subtitle: {text: 'Week begining : ' + startdate },

    xAxis: {
        categories: names,
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        title: {
            text: 'Vacines delivered'
        }
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: 'National Average'
        }

    }],
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:20px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.0f}</b></td><td>avg</td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },


    series: [{
        name: 'Monday',
        data: monday
    }, {
        name: 'Tuesday',
        data: tuesday

    }, {
        name: 'Wednesday',
        data: wednesday

    }, {
        name: 'Thursday',
        data: thursday

    }, {
        name: 'Friday',
        data: friday

    }, {
        name: 'Saturday',
        data: saturday

    }, {
        name: 'Sunday',
        data: sunday

    },
    {
        name: 'Average',
        data: average,
        type: "spline"
    }]
});
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please add your chart code so far and elaborate on what part of the formatting you can not get right? That way it is much easier for us to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I've added my code, should I include the JSON file?

Comment: Yes please. Please add how you generate the data. I think the format mistake is in there.

Comment: names = ["Clinic1", "Clinic1", "Clinic1", "Clinic1", "Clinic1", "Clinic1", "Clinic1"]
monday = [2208, 6769, 1672, 1902, 1045, 1148, 713]
tuesday = [2231, 7044, 1453, 1443, 968, 1778, 704]
wednesday =  [1962, 5254, 1769, 1043, 1171, 1476, 1062]
thursday = [2022, 4804, 1963, 1127, 1775, 1126, 1339]
friday = [1693, 3384, 2046, 1235, 1280, 1179, 1036]
saturday = [896, 2385, 1165, 740, 446, 282, 358]
sunday = [71, 0, 0, 0, 167, 224, 37]
average = [3896, 4385, 3165, 2740, 4446, 3282, 80]

Comment: I reproduced your chart in a JSFiddle, and I don't see what the rendering problem is? https://jsfiddle.net/nf6u1Lme/

Comment: Thanks for that. What I was trying to do was apply the line graph to each group so each clinic could see how they relate to the national average for that day. Again your advice is much appreciated.

Comment: So you want the tooltip format to be different? like: `Monday: 2208 vs <avg>`?

Comment: Apologies I'm not explaining myself very well. I would like to overlay the line chart on each of the weekly groups of columns. The code I posted is a work in progress and I was looking at including the average in the tooltip as an alternative if I can't display it as a graphic.

Comment: So you want to add another line series with the same value for every column group?

Comment: If possible, yes. The national average is a constant that can be applied to all the other groups.